# Proper way to output HTML to the page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I realize this is probably a fundamental thing I should know but I am self-teaching myself C# and asp.net so I am a little lost at this point.

I have a stored procedure, which will return around 700-800 image URLs.

I need to build HTML like this for all the 800 image URLs and return the HTML to the page:

```
<div class="tile">
    <img src="source.png" height="100" width="100" />
</div>
```

This is my code currently:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    string flagwallcontent = ""; //using a string to build html
    while (reader.Read())
    {
     flagwallcontent = flagwallcontent + "<div class='tile'>";   
     flagwallcontent = flagwallcontent + "<img src='" + reader.GetString(0) + "' height='100' width='100'/>";
    flagwallcontent = flagwallcontent + "</div>";
    }
    FlagWallLiteral.Text = flagwallcontent; //returning html to asp literal
}
```

I feel that this is not the efficient way to do it. Using string to build HTML and return HTML to asp literal. Can you suggest what the best way would be?

Comment: It's not inefficient, it's just ugly. If you using Literal control in this case, wouldn't it be better to use some other control, like DataGridView? You can simply bind your `reader` to it and output your list. It's gonn do the looping for you. This way you will keep your HTML and C# logic separated.

Comment: yes, but not datagridview, is there anything that more flexible with html?

Comment: @Zealander, it is inefficient.  For `n` rows, this will allocate `n * 3` strings.  For 100 images, that equates to 1.1 MB of string allocations, for 1000, that is 120 MB of string allocations.  The GC may collect more frequently to reduce the private working set, but it is still quite taxing.  Use a `StringBuilder` if you need to do multiple concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is to have an ASP.NET `Panel` (which renders as a `<div>`) to be the container for each of X hundred images you will add, like this:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
       // Create new image control
       var newImage = new Image ();
       newImage.ImageUrl = reader.GetString(0);
       newImage.Height = 100;
       newImage.Width = 100;

       // Add new image to panel
       Panel1.Controls.Add (newImage);
   }
}
```

This allows ASP.NET to render the HTML while working with the strongly typed C# API.